# Erro ao compilar no Delphi XE5 UPD2

Tags: delphi, compilação

Estou com o seguinte erro ao compilar no Delphi XE5, alguém sabe o que pode ser? começou após uma tentativa frustrada de instalar o XE6.

[image: ERRO BRCC2]

Comment: Aparentemente os paths se perderam, pois ele está procurando o compilador dentro da pasta do seu projeto. O BRCC32 é o compilador de resources. Você possui algum comando na execução pre ou pos build do projeto?

Comment: Acho que tive azar na instalação do XE6 mesmo, realmente não mudei nada na execução, ocorreu de repente.

Comment: já tentou restaurar a instalação do XE5?

Comment: Estou reinstalando mesmo.

Answer (score 2):

Problema resolvido. O antivírus Kaspersky Pure 3 estava bloqueando alguma instância do compilador, este problema começou a ocorrer sem nenhuma configuração no antivirus, provavelmente foi após alguma atualização automática do mesmo.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica.

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece você fez uma instalação customizada do Delphi XE5, ao tentar instalar a versão XE6 você deve ter optado por uma instalação padrão que deve ter alterado as configurações atuais(customizadas), um provável modo para corrigir este erro é mostrado nesse [**artigo**](http://support.embarcadero.com/es/article/42597) feito pela Embarcadero.